# How can I merge the swap and expanding dots page indicators?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-pageview

I am trying to have an indicator effect which merge two different effects with each other , is it possible for the dots to have both the swap effect and for the active dot to have different width to the rest of the dots so it seems expanded to them ? This is the code I have , it just applies the swap effect but I can't apply the expansion factor which seems to be exclusive to the expanding dots effect

```
class _OnboardingViewState extends State<OnboardingView> {
  final pageController = PageController();
  int currentIndex = 0 ;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children:<Widget> [
            PageView.builder(
              controller: pageController,
              itemCount: boardingItems.length,
              onPageChanged: (index){
                setState(() {
                  currentIndex = index;
                });
              },
              itemBuilder: (context,index){
                return Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children:
                  [
                    Image.asset(
                      boardingItems[index].image,fit:BoxFit.fill ,width: double.infinity.w,),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
            Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 12.5.h,),
                  const Spacer(),
                  SmoothPageIndicator(
                    controller: pageController,
                    count:  3,
                    axisDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    effect:  const ExpandingDotsEffect(
                        spacing:  8.0,
                        radius: 1,
                        dotWidth:  25.0,
                        dotHeight:  8.0,
                        dotColor:Colors.grey,
                        activeDotColor: Colors.white
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height:3.5.h,),
                  SizedBox(height: 4.5.h,)
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```